# Logistic regression - One model trained on different groups

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, logistic, inference, group-differences

I have a logistic regression model that trains a set of binary independent variables (X) on a binary response variable (Y).

The data was gathered from different individuals for who also e.g. socio-demographic data exists.

I can therefore split my X and Y into subsets (e.g. by gender) and train the same model for the individual subgroups.

I get for the individual groups different independent variable coefficients.

Say e.g. I have for group 1 and x1 the coefficient β1=0.123 and for group 2 and x1 the coefficient β1=-0.456.

How can I use the coefficients to compare the two groups with respect to the independent variable x1?
What else does me the coefficients tell?
How can I show statistically significant differences between the coefficients (and the independent variables)?

Answer (score 1):

I would do this in one regression that includes gender as a variable and an interaction between gender ($G$) and your $X$ of interest. Then you test the coefficient on the interaction, which measures the difference in $X$ between genders.

$$
logit(\mathbb E[Y\vert X, G]) = \beta_0 +\beta_1X +\beta_2G + \beta_3 XG
$$

This is easy to do in software such as `R`.

```
set.seed(2022)
N <- 100
X <- runif(N)
G <- sample(c("male", "female"), N, replace = TRUE)
y <- rbinom(N, 1, 0.5)
L <- glm(y ~ X*G, family = binomial)
summary(L)
```

I get a p-value on the interaction term of $0.675$. Since the simulated $y$ is independent of my simulated $X$ and $G$, this is not surprising.

For extensions of this idea, you might find yourself interested in [*chunk tests*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27429/what-are-chunk-tests). For instance, if you wanted to consider the `G` variable to have a third `nonbinary` level, you could do the following.

```
library(lmtest)
set.seed(2022)
N <- 100
X <- runif(N)
G <- sample(c("male", "female", "nonbinary"), N, replace = TRUE)
y <- rbinom(N, 1, 0.5)
L0 <- glm(y ~ X + G, family = binomial)
L1 <- glm(y ~ X*G, family = binomial)
lmtest::lrtest(L1, L0)
```

This is analogous to a [*partial F-test*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/157102/what-is-a-partial-f-statistic) in linear regression, which is one example of a chunk test.